# Using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, arithmetic operator and parameter with Firebird

Tags: firebird

Why doesn't this work (when parameter is set to 1) :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMPFIELD > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - ?)
```

But this works :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMPFIELD > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1)
```

I get error message: `"conversion error from string "39723.991882951" "`

I'm using Firebird 2.1

**EDIT:**

I found the answer myself with a little help:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMPFIELD > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - CAST(? as DECIMAL(18,9))
```

Works if the parameter is given as float value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do exactly? Maybe I can be more helpfull with more details.

> SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMPFIELD > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - ?)

How do you set your parameter in your code? Which language do you use?

If you use Delphi, then your parameter should be passed as Float. Ie:

```
MyQuery.ParamByName('delta').asFloat := 0.1;
```

Try this and tell us if it's working

HTH

Comment: It will give ""0,1" is not a valid date and time"

Comment: Can you build your query at runtime, putting the value directly in the quesry instead of using a parameter?

Comment: On top of my head, I think you do not have the choice... Unfortunately, I have to leave work. I'm going to check if the'Res a way tomorrow